# Eclipse 3.7 line wrapping - revisited

Tags: eclipse, perl, line-breaks

I know this has been discussed in many places, but I guess I simply don't understand what's going wrong.

I'm working with Perl files and the Perl Eclispe extension.

What I have is one single line like this (stupid example):

```
my $do += $do_b + $do_c + $do_d + $do_e + $do_f + $do_g + $do_h + $do_i + $do_b + $do_c + $do_d + $do_e + $do_f + $do_g + $do_h + $do_i + $do_b + $do_c + $do_d + $do_e + $do_f + $do_g + $do_h + $do_i;
```

When I run the formatter, I want to keep this line intact. I've tried everything I can think of, setting line wrapping to 500, turning all wrappings off, setting the optional no formatter off before the line and then on again. But no matter what I do, Eclipse breaks the line... It's really weird. I've even tried adding the Java comments `//` at the end, but no luck.

Why can't I to 100% disable line breaks in Eclipse..?

Comment: You might want to ask this question at [SuperUser.com](http://superuser.com/). StackOverflow is about programming.

Comment: Alexis Pigeon, refer to the [SO site FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions): »if your question generally covers […] software tools commonly used by programmers […] then you’re in the right place to ask your question!«

Comment: @daxim I know about the FAQ, thank you. When writing my comment I rather had in mind suggesting that superuser.com could be **another** nice place to ask this too. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

please try this extension,

http://ahtik.com/blog/projects/eclipse-word-wrap/

Do not trust eclipse setting as it changes as you change the editor (java interface to perl or python or FB4Linux)